# How to update direct update pre-defined authentication realm and challenge handler in MobileFirst 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Previously in IBM MobileFirst 7.1 we can update or adjust direct update pre-defined authentication realm and challenge handler using custom security checks in authenticationConfig.xml. For mobileFirst 8.0 applications, how can we use custom security check with direct update pre-defined authentication realm?

Currently, we are developing an application using custom challenge handler and security check. So, when we update a web resources on the server it triggers a direct update on the client's device and updates the web resources and reloads the app. Here, web resources are updated as expected. After reload of app, it was trying to get access token and failed to obtain token from server.

log:

```
04-25 17:10:02.822 7414-8743/com.abc D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader: WLDirectUpdateDownloader.extractZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:320 :: File: views
04-25 17:10:02.825 7414-8743/com.abc D/com.worklight.androidgap.directupdate.WLDirectUpdateDownloader: WLDirectUpdateDownloader.extractZipFile in WLDirectUpdateDownloader.java:353 :: Finish copy files to local storage from updated zip file...
04-25 17:10:04.088 7414-8847/com.abc W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLDirectUpdatePlugin.hideProgressDialog blocked the main thread for 1064ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
04-25 17:10:04.088 7414-8847/com.abc I/Choreographer: Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-25 17:10:04.095 7414-8743/com.abc D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.ChallengeHandlerPlugin: ChallengeHandlerPlugin.execute in ChallengeHandlerPlugin.java:42 :: inside ChallengeHandlerPlugin execute for action cancel
04-25 17:10:04.096 7414-8743/com.abc D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.ChallengeHandlerPlugin: ChallengeHandlerPlugin.execute in ChallengeHandlerPlugin.java:64 :: inside ChallengeHandlerPlugin cancel
04-25 17:10:04.096 7414-8743/com.abc D/wl.resource_request: WLResourceRequest$ObtainAccessTokenListener.onFailure in WLResourceRequest.java:759 :: Resource request failed with status:-1 and error: Challenge handler operation was cancelled.
04-25 17:10:04.099 7414-8743/com.abc D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLResourceRequestPlugin: WLResourceRequestPlugin$1$1.onFailure in WLResourceRequestPlugin.java:92 :: inside WLResourceRequestPlugin failure
04-25 17:10:04.102 7414-8743/com.abc D/WLAuthorizationManagerInternal: WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.onObtainAccessTokenFailure in WLAuthorizationManagerInternal.java:904 :: Obtain AccessToken failed with status code: -1 and error message: Challenge handler operation was cancelled.
04-25 17:10:04.109 7414-8743/com.abc D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLActionSenderPlugin: WLActionSenderPlugin.onDestroy in WLActionSenderPlugin.java:114 :: onDestroy
04-25 17:10:04.112 7414-8743/com.abc D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLActionSenderPlugin: WLActionSenderPlugin.removeActionReceiverIfExists in WLActionSenderPlugin.java:96 :: Receiver :: MIActionReceiverId found. Removing.
04-25 17:10:04.113 7414-8743/com.abc D/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLActionReceiverWithCallbackcontext: WLActionReceiverWithCallbackcontext.releaseCallbackContext in WLActionReceiverWithCallbackcontext.java:50 :: releaseCallbackContext
04-25 17:10:04.206 7414-7414/com.abc I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(142)] "onFailure for fetch tasks adapter call. error:{"status":-1,"responseText":"","responseHeaders":{},"errorMsg":"Challenge handler operation was cancelled.","errorCode":"CHALLENGE_HANDLING_CANCELED"}", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers/myTasks.js (142)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is documented here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_customizing_direct_update_ui_android_wp8_ios.html

The direct update life cycle in 8.0 is highlighted here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_configuring_customizing_direct_update.html

Does this meet your requirement. If not can you provide more information with example

Comment: Thanks Srinivas, We have followed the same documents which you have mentioned. But our question is not about customizing the direct update UI. I have updated my question in detail. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst 7.1 security realms were defined in authenticationConfig.xml. MobileFirst 8.0 this is replaced by security checks defined in adapter.xml. Please refer the below link that details the migration of security realms to MFP 8.
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migrating-security/#migrating-the-resource-adapter